# Can't validate e-mail with javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
```

Is there anything wrong with my validateEmail function that is causing it not to work properly?
https://pastebin.com/KQZSHMn9

Comment: We need to see your function to determine what's going on. Also, more details about "not to work properly". What's a test case that fails? How is it failing?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KQZSHMn9 Here it is. It puts up an error message when I don't enter anything in but it doesn't fail when I don't put in "@" or anything else like that.

Comment: Please include your code in your post, not as a link or an image.
[Why is uploading images of code on Stack Overflow such a big "no no"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It won't let me include it as code for some reason. I copy and pasted it where it told me to but it wouldn't work. I had to put it in pastebin instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't complete; I guess this is because you are a new contributor.
There is an example for email validator code:

```js
function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
{
alert("Valid email address!");
document.form1.text1.focus();
return true;
}
else
{
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
document.form1.text1.focus();
return false;
}
}
```

```css
li {list-style-type: none;
font-size: 16pt;
}
.mail {
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 400px;
background : 
#D8F1F8;
border: 1px soild 
silver;
}
.mail h2 {
margin-left: 38px;
}
input {
font-size: 20pt;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus{
background-color: 
lightyellow;
}
input submit {
font-size: 12pt;
}
.rq {
color: 
#FF0000;
font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript form validation - checking email</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='form-style.css' type='text/css' />      
</head>
<body onload='document.form1.text1.focus()'>
<div class="mail">
<h2>Input an email and Submit</h2>
<form name="form1" action="#"> 
<ul>
<li><input type='text' name='text1'/></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.text1)"/></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<script src="email-validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i'm not sure where I went wrong in my code. Would you be able to explain to me please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QtqpgwC I'm not sure what's wrong with my validateEmail function.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KQZSHMn9 here it is in pastebin.

Comment: @MattyB323 Use regex.

Comment: does it not work in pastebin?